# Where is evdev.c on linux?

Tags: linux, patch

I want to install a patch to get my touchscreen working, but can't seem to find this one file.

Running ubuntu netbook edition 10.10, with no custom kernel.

Comment: `locate evdev.c` or `find -iname evdev.c /usr/src`

Comment: @meagar useful, but not what im looking for. sorry

Comment: Do or do you not want to find the file? Either of those commands will do it.

Comment: the answer below explains everything - the file wans't actually on my system yet... but ill remember to use "locate" next time ive lost a file!

Comment: Use google, there are plenty of sides just linking to files of the linux kernel source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [linux/drivers/input/evdev.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=drivers/input/evdev.c;hb=HEAD) (`apt-get install linux-source`) and [xf86-input-evdev/src/evdev.c](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-evdev/tree/src/evdev.c) (`apt-get source xserver-xorg-input-evdev`).  The former is how the kernel exports input events to userspace through the `/dev/input/eventX` device nodes; the latter is how the X server translates those into X events.  It's not obvious from the question which you mean.

Comment: doesn't that mean I install the whole linux source? *gulp*. Well, if thats the only way I'm gonna get the touchscreen working, it's worth it. How would I recompile it?

Comment: @drnessie: `apt-get install build-essential kernel-package` for prerequisites, and then `make-kpkg` to build the kernel.  At least that's how it used to be; I haven't used Ubuntu in a while, but Debian has moved to a model where `apt-get build-dep linux-meta` and `make deb-pkg` just works, so maybe that's how to do it in Ubuntu now too.

Comment: Oh, and where do I find it after it's been installed? Cos' I've downloaded it but wheres it gone?

Comment: `apt-get install linux-source` goes to `/usr/src/linux-<version>`; `apt-get source <package>` goes to the `./<package>-<version>`.

Comment: and sorry for being an incredible noob, but do you know which version of linux comes with a freshly-installed-yesterday version of ubuntu netbook 10.10?

Comment: @drnessie: Not sure, but if you have it installed, just run `aptitude search 'linux-image ~i'` to see what's currently on the machine.

Comment: nvmind, i've been a pain - the answer came up when i asked it [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483973)